# Node.js + AngularJS + Socket.io : pushed data not available in the controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, angularjs

I've setup my Node server to push out some data at random intervals, and the data is getting to the client/browser; however, I can't figure out how to access it in my app's controller.

```
#node.js file: /server.js (truncated for brevity)

var http    = require('http').createServer(handler),//refers to handler()
    fs      = require('fs'),
    io      = require('socket.io').listen(http);
http.listen(8000);

…

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    /* DUMMY CODE: this generates fake alerts at random intervals */
    (function loop() {
        var rand = Math…;
        …
        setTimeout(function(){
            …
            var alert = { … };

            socket.emit('alert', {
                "alert": alert
            });//socket.emit()

            loop();
        }, rand);
    }());
});//io.sockets.on()
```

When I log `alert` to Terminal, it looks like this:

```
alert: {
    id: 258,
    lat:    -95.20933,
    long:   37.027676,
    neighbourhood: "Downtown",
    time:   //stringified js timestamp
}
```

And `arguments` from below contains the data I want (basically same as `alert`).

```
# /app/js/services.js

angular.module( 'BAR.services' , [])
.factory('socketio', function($rootScope){

    var socket = io.connect();
    return {
        on: function(event, callback) {
            socket.on(event, function(){
                //console.log(arguments);
                $rootScope.$apply(function(){
                    callback.apply(socket, arguments);
                });//$rootScope.$apply()
            });//socket.on()
        },//on
        emit: function(event, data, callback) {
            socket.emit(event, data, function(){
                //console.log(arguments);
                $rootScope.$apply(function(){
                    if (callback) callback.apply(socket, arguments);
                });//$rootScope.$apply()
            });//socket.emit()
        },//emit
        disconnect: function() {
            socket.disconnect();
        }
    }//return

});// AlertServices
```

However, I can't figure out how to access the data from `arguments` in my controller:

```
# /app/js/controllers.js

function Alerts( $scope , socketio ) {

    socketio.on('alert', function(data) {
        console.log(data);      /* I expect this to be the data I want */
        $scope.alert = data.alert;
    });

    $scope.disconnect = function(){
        socketio.disconnect();
    }

}
Alerts.$inject = ['$scope','socketio'];
```

When I log `data` to the browser's console here in the controller, I get an enormous object that seems to be the parent of `$scope`; and `data.alert` is undefined. I also tried to specify a second parameter like this `socketio.on('alert', function( data , args )` thinking it might be `arguments` (since `callback.apply( … )` in services has 2), but when I did and logged it to console, `args` returned undefined.

Btw, I based this on [a tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/frameworks/angular-websockets/) by an AngularJS intern. Different pieces had the same names, so I had a bit trouble figuring out what each the different peices did (also it was not helpful that it was in Jade).

What I really want to do is update a binding in my view with the data from `alert`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `on` and `emit` functions, you're using:

```
socket.on(event, function() {
  $rootScope.$apply(function() {
    callback.apply(socket, arguments);
  });
});
```

but in the original version of this from the tutorial, it says:

```
socket.on(eventName, function() {  
  var args = arguments;
  $rootScope.$apply(function () {
    callback.apply(socket, args);
  });
});
```

The `var args = arguments` is important, as it sets `args` to the arguments passed to the callback to `socket.on` (which is the data you're looking for). Without this step, when you actually use `arguments`, it resolves to the arguments passed into the callback to `$rootScope.$apply` (which is an Angular scope [according to the documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply), explaining why you get the console output you do).

The solution would be to capture the arguments outside of the call to `$apply` and pass those into your callback:

```
socket.on(event, function() {
  var args = arguments;
  $rootScope.$apply(function() {
    callback.apply(socket, args);
  });
});
```

Comment: oh my gosh now that makes sense. I was wondering why he bothered assigning arguments to only use it once. I'll try that in the morning. thanks!

Comment: btw, @btford, thank you for the tutorial! (but please don't name different things with the same name)